# Using python to serve file from directory

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

I'm using simplehttpserver to serve a file from a directory.

I can access it, but if i do

```
>    http://localhost:8000/jtest.py
```

i see the source code, not the output from the code.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're not using the right tool. SimpleHTTPServer doesn't execute `.py`s, just serve them as normal files.

Comment: Sooo, what do i need to make this lightweight?

Comment: You could create an instance of SimpleHttpServer programatically and add new do_GET method that calls your .py file.

Comment: Check this answer, maybe you find something suitable there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067729/python-script-in-a-browser/22067925#22067925